# steepest descent-Optimisation funktion is not converging

Tags: python, optimization, gradient-descent

I need to implement an steepest descent function one without a Armijo step size control and one with.
I implementented it, but it would not converge, to any spot. After try and error, I found out, that my Alpha in my step size control is getting really small. I think that is the issue.

But I have the same problem without a step size control. It just would not converge.

The Test-functions:

```
def f1(x, y):
    return 3*x*x*y - x*x*x - y*y*y*y

def grad_f1(x, y):
    df_dx = 6*x*y - 3*x*x
    df_dy = 3*x*x - 4*y*y*y
    return np.array([df_dx, df_dy])

def f2(x, y, z):
    return 2*x*x - x*y + 2*x*z - y + y*y*y + z*z

def grad_f2(x, y, z):
    df_dx = 4*x - y + 2*z
    df_dy = -x + 3*y*y - 1
    df_dz = 2*x + 2*z
    return np.array([df_dx, df_dy, df_dz])
```

and the code:

```
def steepest_descent_fixed_step(f, grad, init, min=True, alpha=10e-6, max_iters=5, tol=1e-4):
    x = init
    history = [x]
    direction = 1 if min else -1
    for i in range(max_iters):
        gradient = grad(*x)
        if np.linalg.norm(gradient) < tol:
            break
        print(f"{i}. x:{x}\t| Gradient:{direction * alpha * gradient}")
        x = x - direction * alpha * gradient
        history.append(x)
    return history ,i


def armijo_step(f, grad, x, p, alpha=1, c=0.5, rho=0.5, min=True):
    #für minimierung
    if min:
        t = - c * np.dot(grad, p)
        fx = f(*x)
        counter = 0
        while (fx - f(*x + alpha *p) > (alpha * t) ):
            print(f"{counter}. Alpha = {alpha}| Links:{(f(*x + alpha * p))}| Rechts: {f(*x) - c * alpha * np.dot(-p, p)}")   
            counter += 1         
            alpha *= rho
        return alpha
    
    #für maximierung
    if not min:
        while (f(*x + alpha * -p) - f(*x) - c * alpha * np.dot(grad(*x), -p)) > 0:
            alpha *= rho
        return alpha


def steepest_descent_armijo(f, grad, init, max_iters=100, tol=1e-4, min=True):
    x = init
    history = [x]
    
    direction = 1 if min else -1
    for i in range(max_iters):
        
        gradient = grad(*x)
        if np.linalg.norm(gradient) < tol:
            break
        p = -gradient
        alpha = armijo_step(f, gradient, x, p, min=min)
        x = x + direction * alpha * (p/np.linalg.norm(p)) # should be just p
        #print(f"x:{x} | Alpha:{alpha}")
        history.append(x)
    return history , i

def visualize_optimization_simple(f, grad, method, dim, num_points=1000, interval=(-10, 10), min=True):
    random_starts = np.random.uniform(interval[0], interval[1], (num_points, dim))
    
    # Visualisiere die Ergebnisse
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    counter = 0
    for start in random_starts:
        print(f"start:{start}")
        po,i= method(f, grad, start, min=min)
        po = po[-1]
        fpo = f(*po)
        print(f"ende: {counter}. {po}, {fpo},{i})")
        counter += 1



visualize_optimization_simple(f2, grad_f2, steepest_descent_armijo, 3,  num_points=1, min=True)
visualize_optimization_simple(f2, grad_f2, steepest_descent_fixed_step,3,  num_points=1)
```

f1 should be maximize, f2 should be min, the Armijo Condition in min and max is equivalent.

I just do not know what to do anymore and do not see a problem.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: There are a couple of bugs in your code: 1) The `steepest_decent_armijo` function takes the gradient function as an argument, but you pass the calculated `gradient` array. 2) In the case of `f1`, you need to maximise, but you call it to minimise. I also wonder why it is so non-symmetric to the code to minimise (the while condition). I do not know whether the code will run when you fix this. Likely you posted a code broken in a state of desperate trying :-}.